# Symfony2: how to set form action in services.yml

Tags: php, forms, symfony, service

I use a service to get a basic search form on my website. I need to set the action form to a search result page. I can set the form action to be a specific url (/search) but can't use a "generateUrl"-like method in a yaml.

I want to be able to test my form in dev environment /app_dev.php as well as in prod environment. Any suggestion or idea?

**services.yml**

```
parameters:
  form.search.default.value: "search for things"

services:
  app_bundle.form.type.search:
    class: AppBundle\Form\SearchType
    arguments: [AppBundle\Entity\Search]
    tags:
      - { name: form.type, alias: tab_search }

  app_bundle.form.search:
    factory_method: create
    factory_service: form.factory
    class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
    arguments:
      - tab_search
      - @app_bundle.form.entity.search
      - { action: /search } # I'd like something similar to $this->generateUrl("search")

  app_bundle.form.entity.search:
    class: AppBundle\Entity\Search
    arguments: [%form.search.default.value%]
```

**DefaultController.php**

```
        /**
         * @Route("/", name="homepage")
         * @Template()
         */
        public function indexAction(Request $request)
        {
            $form = $this->get('app_bundle.form.search');
            // [...]
            return array('search' => $form->createView());
        }
```

Comment: How about passing a form option named 'action' from Controller instead of Service declaration and then use it in your form class.

Comment: yes that would work but I want to use a service this form will be included in nearly every action of the bundle

Comment: Ok, you could inject 'router' service and your target route to your form class and then call $router->generate(route).

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I've done something like this before with this code:

```
protected $action;

public function setAction($action)
{
    $this->action = $action;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // rest of form configuration
    $builder->setAction($this->action);
}
```

Then in your services.yml:

```
services:
    app_bundle.form.type.search:
    class: AppBundle\Form\SearchType
    arguments: [AppBundle\Entity\Search]
    calls:
        - [setAction, ["%app_bundle.form.type.search.action%"]]      
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: tab_search }
```

And then set the `app_bundle.form.type.search.action` value in parameters somewhere.

If you want to allow the method to be overridden but set a default, set the `action` in `setDefaultOptions` and then override from the controller or a listener.

Comment: ok but how can i set `app_bundle.form.type.search.action` to be `/app_dev.php/search` in dev and `/search` in prod ? I feel like using `config_dev.yml` and `config_prod.yml` is a little bit far fetch...